# Is there a more automated way to spot a substring?

Tags: python, string, substring

I am trying to extract the temperature from a device and i am sending a command through serial to get a response from the machine.
The response (aka the string) is `b'wf_test m_temp \r\nmain card temp=31500 (31.5 oC)\r\n[root@testest:~]# \r\n[root@testest:~]# '`

The code below is working, i was just wondering how i could make it more mobile(meaning that i could use it for other machines, in order to extract their temperature, without having to change the position parameters in order to slice the string at the correct position). I tried the `find` method, but it just gives me the position of the string, and i am not sure how to proceed. Right now the code slices the string that contain the temperature string(31.5) and compares it.

```py
import serial
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', timeout=1)
ser.baudrate = 115200



def temp_read ():
    temp = b"wf_test m_temp \r\n"
    ser.write(temp)
    result = ser.read(1000)
    print(result)
    str1 = str(result)
    str1.find('(')
    str2 = str1[43:47]
    print(str2 +' oC')
    float(str2)
    if float(str2) < 70:
        print('Pass')
    else:
        print('Fail')
```

I would like to be able to spot the `oC` to the string and slice backwards so i can get the temperature and compare it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use regular expressions here, e.g. try using `re.findall`:

```
inp = "wf_test m_temp \r\nmain card temp=31500 (31.5 oC)\r\n[root@testest:~]# \r\n[root@testest:~]# "
temps = re.findall(r'\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?) oC\)', inp)
print(temps)
```

This prints:

```
['31.5']
```

The regex pattern used `\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?) oC\)` will target every temperature which appears as something like `(31.5 oC)`.

**Edit:**

Use the following to obtain the whole number temperatures:

```
temps = re.findall(r'\btemp=(\d+)', inp)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response!
I am not really familiar with regular expressions, so if you have the time, how could i make it print just the string 31.5 or even 31500 so i can make the floating point or integer respectively and compare them to an actual number?
Again thank you!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I want to get the string let's say after the `temp=` which is `31500`,  then i make it an integer and compare it to let's say `70000` which should be the max temp.
If it's over the max temp it's a pass, if it isn't it's a fail.

Comment: Check the edit for an option to find the `temp` values.

Comment: I am getting this error when i try to make it an integer in order to compare it : `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'` but that's for another question, your answer solved the string problem, so i am gonna look how to solve the next issue! Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Rozakos Use `int(temps[0])` for example; you need to access a particular list element string first before calling `int()`.

Comment: Damn, i wish i could upvote you more, that solved the list problem as well! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to recognize the pattern `"\r\n", label, "=", digits` (i.e. `"\r\nmain card temp=31500"`) in the result.

In the following, `matches` is a list of all found temperatures in the string. Usually there should be only one match. So this would print: `"main card temp: Pass"` for your example input.

```
import re
import serial
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', timeout=1)
ser.baudrate = 115200

def temp_read():
    ser.write(b"wf_test m_temp \r\n")
    result = ser.read(1000).decode()
    matches = re.findall(r"\r\n([^=]+)=(\d+)", result)
    if matches:
        # matches will be like [('main card temp', '31500')]
        label = matches[0][0]
        temp = int(matches[0][1]) / 1000
        print(label + ': ' + ('Pass' if temp < 70 else 'Fail'))
    else:
        print('No temperature found in "%s"' % result)
```

The expression is

```
\r\n        # CR + LF
([^=]+)     # group 1 (label): multiple characters other than "="
=           # "="
(\d+)       # group 2 (temp): multiple digits
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but for some reason it doesn't locate the temperature and i am getting the "No Temperature found in" message.

Comment: Ah, this is because you can't use `str()` to convert a byte string into a real string (I took that from the sample code in your question, where it already is wrong). You must use `.decode()`. I've updated my answer (see [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57686813/revisions)), it should work now.

Comment: Ok that's weird, i used both `temp_output = str(ser.read(1000))` and `temp_output = str(ser.read(1000).decode())` and they both worked fine. I knew about the byte string and the `decode` method, but in this case it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: `str(b'\r\ntest')` results in `"b'\\r\\ntest'"`, whereas `b'test'.decode()` results in `"\r\ntest"`. Only the latter is correct. My regex expects that there are actual `\r` and `\n` characters in the string, and `str()` won't give that result. The above definitely works for the sample string you gave.

Comment: @Rozakos See: https://ideone.com/Yg1GFb (I corrected one copy & paste error and of course the number needs to be devided by 1000, not by 100, so use the updated code from my answer)